# Is this a weird structure or correct English? "Thank you to and Thank you you for watching me."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, sentence-structure

At the end of a video on English language exam by a native speaker, he says:

**"Thank you to and Thank you you for watching me. I will see you in the next video."** [IELTS video closing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKkY0tCcfBM) (see: 14:55-15:02)

1- Regarding the first part **"thank you to and .... "**; why isn't **"to"** followed by a person whom he is thanking for such as "**Thank you to John."**? Is this sentence missing something after **"to"**?

2- Why does he use **"you"** two times in the second part **"thank you you for ...."?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He says not *Thank you to*, but *Thank you, Thu*, addressing the woman he has just interviewed. *Thu* is her name.

He follows that with *Thank you, you* to address all his audience. Although this construction is certainly not typical, one gets the feeling that it occurs to him in the moment and that it appeals to him because of its rhyme.

Comment: I wouldn't have been surprised if he'd piled on the alliteration - *Thank you Thu, and thank you **you too...***